# Associated users endpoint gives empty response for meta users

Tags: bug, user-accounts, per-site-meta, api, linked-accounts

The [`/users/{ids}/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#pagesize=100&ids=17341075&types=meta_site&filter=default&run=true) endpoint of the Stack Exchange API has the option to set `?types=meta_site` to get the child meta users of a network account. But [when I try it now](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#pagesize=100&ids=17341075&types=meta_site&filter=default&run=true), I get an empty response for my account (and any other account ID I try).

Making a `GET` request to [`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/17341075/associated?pagesize=100&types=meta_site`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/17341075/associated?pagesize=100&types=meta_site)
gives (formatted):

```json
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9965
}
```

But I *do* have automatically-created accounts on per-site metas! This issue occurs on all API versions.

I have an API client that tries to find all the sites that I have accounts on (that meet certain criteria) by using the `/users/{ids}/associated` endpoint. But it seems the only way it can find my active accounts on child metas is to check each site I have a main account on individually, due to this bug.

Comment: I reported that bug on Stack Apps: [/me/associated doesn't return meta sites anymore](https://stackapps.com/q/8666/34061)

Comment: @Glorfindel Maybe after 1,5 years it will finally get some attention then :-)

Comment: Still happening for me, I try all of the `type` options, `paging` options, and all I get back in the `main_sites`. It shows in the total the correct number of `main_sites` + `meta_sites` (`58` for me), but just doesn't display them.  [my broken link here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=1&pagesize=60&ids=1895213&types=main_site%3Bmeta_site&filter=!2.E*KTn*l*W4jGP2jDVwz)